# How can I perform skip and take functions in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have 161 columns and each column have above 50K data.I have to show this info for each column in line graph.If try to show this info in Line graph then it will take more time to draw graph.

**Problem :**

Now I decided to divide the data corresponding to each column.Like for column1 take first 50 rows take average then take second 50 rows and so on. This process will continue for all columns.

How I can do this in SQL. I have done it in C# but I want to do this on SQL server end.

```
 public static IEnumerable<double> CheckRateValue(this IEnumerable<double> values)
    {

            int i = 1;
            int j = 0;
            for (; i < values.Count(); )
            {
                yield return values.Skip(j * 2).Take(2).Average();
                i = i + 2;
                j++;
            }


    }
```

Comment: The syntax is specific to your RDBMS engine: it is different for Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc. Please add a tag for the SQL "dialect" that you are looking for. By the way, your C# code does the expensive part on the SQL side - it does not skip/take in memory, and it talks to your RDBMS in the correct dialect.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks for this useful info now check.Is it right now?Do you have any idea to implement this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [row_number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

```
declare @Skip int = 20
declare @Take int = 10

select SomeColumn
from (
       select SomeColumn,
              row_number() over(order by SomeColumnToOrderBy) as rn
       from YourTable
     ) T
where rn > @Skip and 
      rn <= @Skip + @Take
```

Comment: thanks for reply.I have two column first column is Datetime column(PK) and second column is S_E1(float).I try to execute your query but it retrn only 0 values for S_E1.Where i am wrong here ?

Comment: Don't know. You can try the query [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/70553/paging) on SE-Data.

Comment: There should be an [edit query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/70553) link below the query. Otherwise you can just copy/paste the query to a [new query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)