# Is there a SQL select qualifier to perform a Skip() and Take()

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, db2

We are trying to do the equivalent of a LINQ `select.Skip(50).Take(25)`. This is for a library that can hit any SQL database. So...

1. Is there a standard SQL select clause that can do this? ([Pretty sure the answer is no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646847/how-i-can-perform-skip-and-take-functions-in-sql).)
2. If not, is there a way to do so specifically for Access, DB2, MySql, Oracle, PostgreSQL, & Sql Server? And if so, how for each of those vendors?

Comment: MySQL: `Limit 50, 25`. With a little effort you can do this in every DB engine with ROWNUMBER and PARTITION queries.

Comment: `row_number` *is* a standard SQL way but neither MySQL nor Access support it.

Comment: You'll be hard pressed to find standardization between Access and other engines.

Answer (score 5):

In DB2, there's not really an easy clause like `LIMIT` in MySQL, although you can enable MySQL compatibility when you're on DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows:

```
db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=MYS
db2stop
db2start
```

Alternatively, you can use the ROW_NUMBER() windowing function to get something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
        ,S.*
    FROM your_table AS S
) AS A
WHERE rn BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

Comment: Using a window function **is** the ANSI standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

For MySQL, use LIMIT. With one argument, it is the number of rows to return. With two arguments, it is the number of rows to skip and then the number of rows to return.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html for details and examples.